# How to extrude geo using color ramp data

Tags: geometry-nodes

is it possible to use a color ramp and get black and white data to extrude faces of a grid?
my goal would be to mimic these kind of basaltic rocks stairs effect
is it doable in geo nodes or only using image texture in shading editor ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good starting point for you. By decimating a grid first ( with the Decimate (Collapse) modifier) you can then use the Dual Mesh node to get the hexagonal shapes. The effect you are after happens on the "Extrude node". The key is to create a series of masks for both your selection and the offset scale.

[image]

Here for example i built out a ramp using a math expression and bluring the result.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Badboi3d

Comment: shapes are looking pretty symmetrical not as yours i might missed something, any idea ?
when i decimate more i have better variety of shapes but ofc less geometry https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWdmJ.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOMR9.png

Comment: Hello Badboi .. very  nice answer! I think it would help folks  if you  share a blend on https://blend-exchange.com/  to cover some of the hidden details, if that's at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @ant0, I found that stacking a couple of Decimate modifiers with different ratios helped a bit if I wasn't imagining things...

Comment: i have added 3 decimate modifier  and i looks already bit better.  dont know if its the rightway to dot it may Badboi tell us what he thinks.
I didnt find how to create the color ramp mask